# JavaScript object search and get all possible nodes

Tags: javascript

I have a multidimensional object. I need to search a string in each node and need to return an array of nodes contains the string.

e.g.

**Object**

```
{
  "data": {
    "countries": "['abc','pqr','xyz']",
    "movies": {
      "actor": "['abc','pqr','xyz']",
      "movie": "['abc','pqr','x toyz']"
    }
  }
```

and if I want to search 'pq' I need an array with

```
countries:pqr
movies:actor:pqr
countries:movie:pqr
```

as the result.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you need to search for - like are you looking for a specific key in the JSON or a specific value? Do you have any example input and example output that could be looked at to better understand the nature of the question?

Comment: i just update the question can you understand ?

Comment: That's quite a bit easier to understand. I've got an idea for a solution. I'll have it up quickly.

Comment: Are you looking for a partial match, or is 'pq' just a typo?

Comment: Looking for a partial match

Comment: @Vigikaran: Your JSON wasn't properly formatted but I think that the solution I just posted gives the output that you wanted. Also, I accidentally searched for 'pqr' instead of 'pq' but it should work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and solve this with recursive function calls

```
function parse(string, key, before) {
    return before+key+":"+string;
}

function findString(string, json, before) {
    var results = [];
    for (var key in json) {
        if (typeof(json[key]) === "string") { // it is a string
            if (json[key].contains(string)) { // it contains what it needs to
              results.push(parse(string, key, before));
          }
        } else { // it is an object
            Array.prototype.push.apply(results, findString(string, json[key], before+key+":"));
        }
    }
    return results;
}

var json = {
   data: {
    countries: "['abc','pqr','xyz']",
    movies: {
      actor: "['abc','pqr','xyz']",
      movie: "['abc','pqr','x toyz']"
    },
    oranges: {
       potatoes: "['abc','pqr','xyz']",
       zebras: {
           lions: "['abc','pqr','xyz']",
           tigers: "oh my!" // does not get added
       }
    }
    }
};

console.log(findString("pqr", json.data, ""));
```

This outputs an array like:

```
Array [ "countries:pqr", "movies:actor:pqr", "movies:movie:pqr", "oranges:potatoes:pqr", "oranges:zebras:lions:pqr" ]
```

Comment: This is working as expected, Than you for your answer

Comment: I'm glad that it helped out! One thing to be aware of is that the check that I'm doing to see if the string can be found is a check within the entire string. So I have it looking at the entire string like `['abc','pqr','xyz']`. If you wanted it to only look at the values inside the string like `abc`, `pqr`, and `xyz` you would have to change this line `if (json[key].contains(string))` to have more complex logic.

Comment: do you know how to use the same in php ?

Comment: I don't know PHP but hopefully the algorithm in JavaScript can help you work out a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {
  "countries": "['abc','pqr','xyz']",
  "movies": {
    "actor": "['abc','pqr','xyz']",
    "movie": "['abc','pqr','x toyz']"
  }
}

var listAll = function(obj, match, parent){
  for( var key in obj ){
    if( typeof obj[key] === "string" ){
      for( var word of obj[key].split("'") ){
        if( word.indexOf(match) !== -1){
          if( !parent ){
            console.log( key + ':' + word );
          }
          else{ console.log( parent+":"+key + ':' + word ); }
        }
      }
    }else{
      listAll(obj[key], match, (parent||'') + key);
    }
  }
}

listAll(data,'pq');

> countries:pqr
> movies:actor:pqr
> movies:movie:pqr
```

Now it should include the full parent list

Comment: In his sample output he did show `movies:actor:pqr` which would suggest the full list of parent objects was important.