# How to search object in nested object by property and return object with parent object's key and value?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I have a nested object

```
let data = {
  address: "123 Street, state, country",
  childObject1: {
    foo: ["bar"],
    person: "Hailey"
  },
  relatedCustomers: {
    childObject: {
      foo: ["bar"],
      person: "Hailey2"
    }
  }
};
```

I want to search object with keys and values by property.

For example

search - my function

data - nested object

```
search("person", data)
```

I get the object

```
{
  childObject: "Hailey2",
  childObject1: "Hailey"
}
```

I write the code which search all values with person:

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-pascal-qyvjw

but I can't get parent object key and get object as a result:

```
{
  childObject: "Hailey2",
  childObject1: "Hailey"
}
```

Comment: In your case, the `childObject` keys are different. What if they are both `childObject`? If you use `search("address", data)`, what should be the output since there are no `parent` keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript object search and get all possible nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638829/javascript-object-search-and-get-all-possible-nodes)

Comment: childObject и childObject1 contain key person that is why
we have object with these keys and values from person property

Answer (score 6):

Please use following code to find the parent key:

```
let search = (needle, parentKey, haystack, found = []) => {
  Object.keys(haystack).forEach(key => {
    if (key === needle) {
      found.push({
        [key]: haystack[key],
        parentKey
      });
      return found;
    }
    if (typeof haystack[key] === "object") {
      search(needle, key, haystack[key], found);
    }
  });
  return found;
};

console.log(search("person", "data", data));
`;
```

I have just passed the parent key in the function and saved it if required. I hope this is what you are looking for. Thanks.